# Securely submit form using JavaScript / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, post, encryption, form-submit

Before asking the question, I admit that this method is uberly discouraged and not secure. I am aware that to achieve this is through SSL.

However, I am developing an HTML5 apps (and it seems that implementing the SSL approach would take a lot of time) and I would like to know the best way to POST a form content.

i.e I have the following form

```
<form id="someform" name="someform" method="POST" action="some/server/url">
```

The way this form is submitted (currently) is using ajax $("#someform).serialize() and so on..

Using this implementation I am facing with (at least) these 2 immediate problems:

1. User could use tools (i.e TamperData | a firefox addons) to modify the posted content (Interception-and-modify).
2. User could forge the data by sending 'fake'submission (Forging)

I am wondering if there is somehow I could at least (obfuscate the POST-ed) value.

I came across with this great http://www.jcryption.org/ tools, but not sure how should I implement it to workaround the problem I am facing.

ps: again I am aware that relying on client-side script is way less secure compared with handling all execution from within the server-side.

framework + language I am using is: CodeIgniter + PHP + JavaScript (jquery)

**1st Amendment:**

I am sure there is at least a work around using this theory

First, I am not too worried about the confidentiality part of my data, that is the POST-ed value will not give any valuable information even if someone else knows what it is.

What concerns me though is the integrity and the authenticity of the POST-ed value. This is simply means that no one else should tamper the information once its being transmitted (once the submit button is clicked), nor anyone could forge or create a fake value (spoofing the server).

This theory leads to digital signature, where (again in theory) I should somehow sign the POST-ed value using server PUB-key, then hash the POST-ed value using the server PUB-key and finally send both the original POST-ed value along with the hashed value.

Prior sending the POST-ed value, the client MUST request for the server PUB-key, so the client can hash the POST-ed value. The server could probably store the PUB-key information along with SESSION information.

Then the server will have to (again) hash (this time with the server PRI-key) the original POST-ed value (sent by client) and compare the two hashed value. If those value is the same, it simply means it is authentic.

Now the part which I am yet to understand is the HOW.....

is there any tools/frameworks/plugins/tutorial/example on how to do this? since it would be too much for me (not to mention the limited amount of time I have) for developing the whole Public-Key-Infrastructure from scratch

Answer (score 3):

Take one step further and realize that a user can encrypt faked data as well.
And SSL won't help against such a tampering.

That's a web-development axiom: **everything can be faked on the client side. Period.**

So, instead of encrypting anything, just verify your input on the server side, like every other site does.

Use `sessions` to store the data that a user should have no access to.

Comment: @Your_Common_Sense, even with session, "authenticated" user can fake the data. Also, how should i verify my input?

Comment: No, they can't tamper on a session data. That's the very point of the mechanism, as session data stored on the server side. Verify your input usual way.

Comment: If i have to be brutally honest with you, i am still not sure if i can follow your suggestion. How could i verify the user input (looking from the technical perspective)?

Comment: Just do not expect valid data from the client and validate it manually. that's all. I don't understand your misunderstanding in turn - input data validation is a cornerstone of web-programming, every site in the world does it. To validate input is ALL that a server can do against tampering.

Answer (score -1):

User

**Spoofed Form Submissions**

You will get full info [here](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html)

Comment: Don;t know why. Please dare to comment , if you dare to downvote